# Angular wait for service response

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm working on a service to call the google geocoding API. However, I have to click on my button twice for the input to display. Is there a way to wait for the input field to be updated only after it has a response?

HTML

```
<img src="../../../assets/customer/Location_Icon.svg" id="locationIcon" (click)="getLocation()">
    <input class="form-control form-control-lg" id="addressSelect" type="text" placeholder="Address" formControlName="location">
```

Typescript

```
// Retrieve location based on current location
  getLocation(){
    // Checks if GPS is supported
    if(navigator.geolocation){
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(response => {
        this.curPosition = this.addressService.retrieveLocation(response);
        this.details.get('location').setValue(this.curPosition);      
      });
    } else {
      alert("Geolocation is not supported by this device")
    }
  }
```

Service

```
  locResponse: any;
  curLocation: string;
  reverseGeo: string = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?";

  // Retrieves location based on coordinates
  retrieveLocation(position:any){
    // If else statement prevents user from spamming the API
    if(this.curLocation != undefined){
      return this.curLocation
    } else{
      // Calls the API if location is empty
      this.http.get(this.reverseGeo + "latlng=" + position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude + "&key=" + this.key).subscribe(response =>{
        // Converts response into type <any> to prevent error message
        this.locResponse = response;
        this.curLocation = this.locResponse.results[0].formatted_address;
        console.warn(this.curLocation)
        return this.curLocation;
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below modified Service which returns you observable in both condition. import `of` ,`map` and `tap` operator of rxjs :

```
retrieveLocation(position: any){
  // If else statement prevents user from spamming the API
  if (this.curLocation != undefined) {
    return of(this.curLocation)
  } else {
    // Calls the API if location is empty
    return this.http.get(this.reverseGeo + "latlng=" + position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude + "&key=" + this.key).pipe(
      tap(response => {
        // Converts response into type <any> to prevent error message
        this.locResponse = response;
        this.curLocation = this.locResponse.results[0].formatted_address;
        console.warn(this.curLocation)
        // return this.curLocation;
      }),
      map(res =>{
        return res.results[0].formatted_address // here return ur formatter address
      })
    )
  }
}
```

and in typescript

```
    getLocation() {
    // Checks if GPS is supported
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(response => {
        
          this.addressService.retrieveLocation(response).subscribe(res = {
            this.curPosition = res;
            this.details.get('location').setValue(this.curPosition);
          });
      });
    } else {
      alert("Geolocation is not supported by this device")
    }
  }
```